# Cancel input file close dialog element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dialog to show to user an input type file. I have an issue when the user canceled the input file or when he chooses the same file, that closes my dialog. I don't want that, so I added event Listener 'cancel' with event prevent default. But that didn't work.

```html
<button id="openDialogButton">Open dialog</button>

<dialog id="dialog">
  <h1>Hi, I'm a dialog !</h1>

  <input type='file'>

  <p><button id="closeDialogButton">Close dialog</button></p>
</dialog>
```

```js
const buttonOpen = document.querySelector("#openDialogButton");
const buttonClose = document.querySelector("#closeDialogButton");
const dialog = document.querySelector("#dialog");

buttonOpen.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  dialog.showModal();
});

buttonClose.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  dialog.close();
});

dialog.addEventListener("cancel", (e) => {
  console.log(e);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

codepen here : https://codepen.io/catif/pen/LYgKNmN

Comment: Seems like a bug of chrome (tested in firefox work as expect)

Comment: You are right, works only with Firefox, not with all chromium browsers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known Chromium bug [#1449848](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1449848).

For a temp workaround, we can call file picker by JS in a created input node, then replace the old one with it. [Demo](https://codepen.io/yuansa/pen/ZEmRBep)

The following demo may have memory leaking issues (not checked carefully) and the style is not 100% aligned with the native input tag.

```js
/** @type {HTMLDialogElement} dialog */
const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");
/** @type {HTMLButtonElement} dialog */
const button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", () => dialog.showModal());

/** @type {HTMLButtonElement} dialog */
const pickFileButton = document.getElementById("pick-file-button");
/** @type {HTMLSpanElement} dialog */
const fileName = document.getElementById("file-name");
pickFileButton.addEventListener("click", handlePickFileByCustomButton);

const filePickerId = "file-picker";
async function handlePickFileByCustomButton() {
  const file = await pickFile();
  /** @type {HTMLInputElement} dialog */
  let inputTag = document.getElementById(filePickerId).cloneNode();
  /** @type {HTMLInputElement} dialog */
  const pickFileInput = document.getElementById("pick-file-input");
  inputTag.style.display = pickFileInput.style.display;
  migrateElementAttributes(pickFileInput, inputTag);
  pickFileInput.parentElement.replaceChild(inputTag, pickFileInput);
  fileName.innerText = Array.from(file)
    .map((fileItem) => fileItem.name)
    .join(", ");
}

/** @return {Promise<FileList>} */
function pickFile() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} dialog */
    let inputTag = document.getElementById(filePickerId);
    if (!inputTag) {
      inputTag = document.createElement("input");
      inputTag.type = "file";
      inputTag.id = filePickerId;
      inputTag.style.display = "none";
      document.body.appendChild(inputTag);
    }
    inputTag.onchange = () => {
      if (!inputTag?.files || !inputTag?.value) {
        return;
      }
      resolve(inputTag.files);
    };
    inputTag.click();
  });
}

/**
 * Copy attributes from the existing input element to the new input element
 *
 * @argument {HTMLInputElement} templateElement
 * @argument {HTMLInputElement} targetElement
 */
function migrateElementAttributes(templateElement, targetElement) {
  Array.from(templateElement.attributes).forEach((attr) => {
    if (attr.name !== "files" && attr.name !== "value") {
      targetElement.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#pick-file-wrapper {
  width: 252.5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4px;
}
#pick-file-input {
  display: none;
}
#pick-file-button {
  max-width: 253px;
  font-size: smaller;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
#file-name {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex: auto;
}
#form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  gap: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<dialog id="dialog">
  <form id="form">
    <label>Buggy <code>input</code></label>
    <input type="file" />
    <label>Patched <code>input</code></label>
    <div id="pick-file-wrapper">
      <button id="pick-file-button" type="button">Choose File</button>
      <span id="file-name">No file chosen</span>
      <input id="pick-file-input" type="file" />
    </div>
  </form>
</dialog>
<button id="button">Open dialog</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I already added a solution but, I don't know why, but someone deleted my answer...

I wish your response will stay here instead of mine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that preventing the dialog from closing when you cancels/add same file selection is not directly achievable with the current dialog implementation.
One alternative solution is to create a custom dialog using HTML and CSS, and handle the file selection logic manually.

```js
const buttonOpen = document.querySelector("#openDialogButton");
const buttonClose = document.querySelector("#closeDialogButton");
const dialog = document.querySelector("#customDialog");
const fileInput = document.querySelector("#fileInput");

buttonOpen.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.style.display = "block";
});

buttonClose.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.style.display = "none";
});

fileInput.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
  if (!selectedFile) {
    return; // Ignore if no file is selected
  }

  // Handle the selected file here
  console.log("Selected file:", selectedFile);
});
```

```css
.custom-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="openDialogButton">Open dialog</button>

<div id="customDialog" class="custom-dialog">
  <h1>Hi, I'm a dialog!</h1>

  <input type="file" id="fileInput">

  <p><button id="closeDialogButton">Close dialog</button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that not the issue here, I know I can create my own modal. I will just want to understand the issue of dialog element. And I answered with the reported issue on chromium.

Comment: Okay. It's due to different browser implementations and event handling for the file input element.